# Canvas HTML5 inheritance

Tags: javascript, html, inheritance, canvas

I need an advice on how to implement inheritance with Canvas.

I have a class(function) "Control" which creates div element, then creates canvas inside this div and then draws on this canvas a rectangular filled with some color.
I want to implement inheritance that is Class "Button" is a child of "Control" and adds to this rectangular some new elements for example text, pictures e.t.c

Answer (score 0):

You should probably start by reading up on [classical inheritance in Javascript](http://javascript.crockford.com/inheritance.html).

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript You can inherit from other functions (constructors) using this syntax:

```
function Control () {
}

function Button () {
}

Button.prototype = new Control;
```

You can add new methods to Button constructor like this:

```
Button.prototype.setText = function() {
}
```

I wouldn't recommend You to get too excited using this approach though.

Comment: Why? Which approach you would recommend?